# Converting a 3D numpy array to instance list (instance_dict={ "instance_key_1": "value", ...}) in Python

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, google-cloud-automl

I am trying to convert a 3D numpy array (from an image) into an instance list, to be fed to an ML model hosted on gcloud.

My preprocessing routine looks like this:

```
def read_image(file_path):
    image = load_img(file_path, target_size=(300, 300)) 
    image = img_to_array(image) 
    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    image /= 255. 
    image=np.array(image).tolist()
    return image
```

According to Gcloud my instance format needs to be like this:

`instance_dict={ "instance_key_1": "value", ...}`

But I'm getting the error in my console:

> error": "Failed to process element: 0 key: content of instances list. Error: Invalid argument: JSON object: does not have named input: content

This may be a simple question, but what am I missing here? Is it how I'm converting the array to a list? When I print just the numpy array it looks like this:

```
   [0.63529414 0.8039216  0.87058824]
   [0.6392157  0.80784315 0.8745098 ]
   ...
   [0.4627451  0.44705883 0.44313726]
   [0.49019608 0.4745098  0.47058824]
   [0.4745098  0.45882353 0.45490196]]
```

Answer (score 1):

As instance_dict is a dict you should pass the dict object of your image . for each image you should generate a unique key and make a dict your function is something like this:

```py
def read_image(all_file_path):
    instance_dict = {}
    for counter,file_path in enumerate(all_file_path):
        image = load_img(file_path, target_size=(300, 300)) 
        image = img_to_array(image) 
        image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
        image /= 255. 
        image=np.array(image).tolist()
        instance_dict['instance'+str(counter)] = image
    return instance_dict
```

Comment: That works, up to a point - I keep getting the error ```"[Errno 21] Is a directory: '/' ``` The path I'm feeding to it is in a directory on my computer: ```path = "/Users/iamreddy831/Desktop/ArchitecturalStyle_ML/FinalTests/testimage1.jpg"```

Comment: checkout the all_file_path list. There is an invalid image path.